# In Orchard CMS, is there a way to display a list based on tags of a content type?

Tags: orchardcms

I created a custom content type "books" and I'm attaching tags to each item (i.e. "Featured", "New", "Children's", "Adults").

I'd like to create lists of books to display based on their tag. For example, I'd like a "Featured" list that displays all the books that have been tagged "Featured", and a "Children's Books" list that displays all the books that have been tagged "Children's".

Is there a simple way to do this (for a visual UI person who's blood pressure rises every time she has to go into the code?) :)

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomies are the best way to do this. Well, tags can do that too but taxonomies are much richer.
So simplest way: yoursite/tags/featured will display all contents tagged with "featured". A little more elaborate way: taxonomies.

Comment: yoursite/tags/featured will display everything with that tag, but I'd like to show multiple "tag" lists on the same page. Can I do that with taxonomy?

Comment: Yes. It comes with widgets that can display what's under a given term. Include several of those widgets and you're done.

Comment: That almost gets me there... Thanks for your help, btw. :) The widget displays a list of ALL the taxonomy terms for a particular parent term. I want to show highlights of each specific term. So say I have a taxonomy term called "Age", then I have a child term called "Children", and another child term called "Adults". On my page I want to have the heading "Children", then underneath, list 4 or 5 "books" that are associated with the taxonomy term "Children". On the same page I also want to have 4 or 5 books under "Adults" that have been associated with that term.

Comment: My only guess would be to add the "Custom Properties" part to my "Books" Content Type so I can filter the lists- but how do I automatically populate the Custom Filter for a list with a Taxonomy term...?

Comment: No custom properties are not for that. If you need something more custom than what taxonomies are providing, either write your own query in code, or wait for Orchard 1.4 and its projector module.